# Using the level vs change in independent variable

Tags: panel-data

I'm running a panel fixed-effect model where the dependent variable is the level of diversification and the main independent variable is the level of liquidity of each individual banks (using annual data). When I run the regressions, I get a negative coefficient, suggesting that higher levels of liquidity reduces the level of bank diversification. However, when I run the same regression by taking the change in annual liquidity as the main independent variable (instead of the level of liquidity), the coefficient is positive, indicating that higher the change in  liquidity, higher the diversification.

I'm confused by these results. My questions is

01) How should I interpret the results of the two regressions?
02) If, according to the results of the first regression, higher level of liquidity causes a decline in the level of diversification, doesn't that essentially imply that a change in liquidity should also has a negative impact on the level of diversification?

The level of liquidity only has positive values.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The change in liquidity could be positive of negative.  Your signs will change depending on whether you measure the change in liquidity as $Year_1 - Year_2$ vs. $Year_2 - Year_1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I took the change as Year 2 - Year 1